# spring boot logback with concurrence

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

I'm using spring-boot 1.5.2.RELEASE with logback.

my logback-spring.xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!-- Reference Manual http://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html -->
 <configuration>
      <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
          <encoder charset="UTF-8"> 
               <pattern>[%level] %date{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}  %-30.30logger{30} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
          </encoder>
      </appender>
      <appender name="RollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
          <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
          <fileNamePattern>logs/log.log</fileNamePattern>
          <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
          </rollingPolicy>
         <encoder>
              <pattern>[%level] %date{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}  %-30.30logger{30} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
          </encoder>
     </appender>     
     <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
     </root>
</configuration>
```

If there is small access, the log looks fine, if in the high concurrence. The log file is disordered.

> - [INFO] 17:18:51.848  [WebLogAspect.java:31] Total cost time : 847 ms
> - [INFO] 17:18:51.860  [HttpClientUtil.java:48] Http request time : 540 ms
> - [INFO] 17:18:51.862  [WebLogAspect.java:31] Total cost time : 552 ms
> - [INFO] 17:18:52.124  [HttpClientUtil.java:48] Http request time : 1632 ms
> - [INFO] 17:18:52.125  [HttpClientUtil.java:48] Http request time : 1517 ms
> - [INFO] 17:18:52.133  [HttpClientUtil.java:48] Http request time : 1432 ms
> - [INFO] 17:18:52.135  [HttpClientUtil.java:48] Http request time : 632 ms
> - [INFO] 17:18:52.199  [HttpClientUtil.java:48] Http request time : 832 ms
> - [INFO] 17:18:52.662  [WebLogAspect.java:31] Total cost time : 1736 ms
> - [INFO] 17:18:52.692  [WebLogAspect.java:31] Total cost time : 1536 ms
> - [INFO] 17:18:52.698  [WebLogAspect.java:31] Total cost time : 1692 ms

It will be fine at the begin, after a while, the log is disordered.

Comment: what do you mean by disordered?

Comment: The correct log should **Total cost time** then **Http request time**, but the log shows  **Http cost time** multiple times then others.

Comment: It depends on your implementation, it can be that way if your method and log are both synchronized (I'd be surprised). However the count of the two should be matched.

Comment: You've got multiple threads interleaving access to your code. If you want the times to appear together then you need to record the timing data and log it as one single line containing both times.